# How to get Past Password in TDLib Telegram Test User Auth

Tags: telegram, tdlib

I am learning how to interact with TDLib, and I first use `SetTdlibParameters` and use these test user credentials:

```
Phone: 9996621111
Code: 22222
```

This works and my app moves on to this state:

```
AuthorizationStateWaitPhoneNumber
```

Then shortly after that I see:

```
AuthorizationStateWaitCode
```

And I pass the `22222` code. At this point, I expect to be authenticated, but the next state I see is:

```
AuthorizationStateWaitPassword
```

Is there a test password I'm supposed to use? Or am I doing something wrong in authenticating with the phone and code? I have read [the documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth#test-accounts) and I don't see what to do from here.

How do I finish this test user authentication flow?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the password was... wait for it...

```
1234
```

I deduced this because I could see a password hint in the logs of `4321` and everyone know that you just reverse the characters of a password hint to get the password.